# How to refactor flex basis for every item with custom width?

Tags: sass, flexbox

I want to have it optimized for this sort of situation where I have items and I want them to be flexible in width. writing a class for every possible item width is not suitable. What could be the ideal and most optimized solution for "flex-basis"? Instead of writing so many classes what can I do?

```
 .flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    &-item-base{
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .item-80{
        flex-basis: 80%;
    }

    .item-70{
        flex-basis: 70%;
    }

    .item-60{
        flex-basis: 60%;
    }

    .item-50{
        flex-basis: 50%;
    }

    .item-40{
        flex-basis: 40%;
    }

    .item-30{
        flex-basis: 30%;
    }

    .item-20{
        flex-basis: 20%;
    }

    .item-10{
        flex-basis: 5%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make an array and loop it. Simple example: $sizes: 80,70,60; Loop using '@each'  and then: .item-#{$size} { flex-basis: $size%; }

Comment: @LaisFrigerio its giving me error on % for flex-basis: $size%, why is that so?

Comment: Hello, @Muhammad Hasan Shahid Sorry for to late. I have a new approach: declare a viariable like $percentage: '%'; And in the loop do it: flex-basis: #{$size}#{$percentage}. We can concatenate variables